# Refer AWS Account number inside IAM policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

For the sake of the automation, I want my IAM policies to be generic.

I am aware that `${aws:username}` fetches username of the policy to whom it is applied to.

Is it possible to do the same for AWS Account number `arn:aws:iam::1234567890:user/${aws:username}` with something like this  `arn:aws:iam::${aws:accountnumber}:user/${aws:username}` inside an IAM policy.

Edited:
Allowed variables are listed in the document linked below. 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html

Comment: What is the specific context in which you are trying to use an ARN containing an account id where it makes sense for the account-id to be a variable, and -- importantly, I suspect -- *which* account ID should it resolve to?  The account owning the policy or the account of the principal whose access is being tested against the policy?  While there is no policy variable for this, there might be a correct solution to what you are actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Later, the account against which the policy is tested. I plan on uploading the policies onto corresponding the accounts, individually. Is there another solution?

Comment: Establish a trust relationship with the other account. The trust relationship, not the policy, includes the other account number.

Comment: I don't see that you've fully answered the question I asked about specific context. 
To clarify: In what condition key or resource ARN would you be testing account numbers, for what kind of action?

Comment: Interestingly enough, a year later I'm finding myself in the very same spot with the very same constraints. My take is to investigate if Cloud Development Kit can provide tools to address these shortcomings, and as a very last option to render the templates on-demand with the deployment pipeline.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

AWS IAM Policy Variables does not allow references for AWS Account Names. Hence there is no way to dynamically refer to the account number in the IAM policy.

Answer (score 2):

In [AWS CDK documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/python/aws_cdk.core/Stack.html) we find the following predefined variables:

- `Aws.accountId`
- `Aws.region`
- `Aws.stackName`

Therefore, you can use the following variables in cloudformation:

- `${AWS::Region}`
- `${AWS::AccountId}`
- `${AWS::StackName}`

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get account number that I found is via STS. Here's Java code that I use to get the account number that works with credentials from AssumeRole as well,

```
String awsRegion = Regions.US_EAST_1;
AWSCredentials cred = new BasicAWSCredentials("access_key_id", "secret_key_id");
// AWSCredentials cred = BasicSessionCredentials(sessionCredentials.getAccessKeyId(),sessionCredentials.getSecretAccessKey(), sessionCredentials.getSessionToken());

AWSSecurityTokenService stsClient = AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder.standard()
        .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(cred))
        .withRegion(awsRegion)
        .build();
String awsAccountNumber = stsClient.getCallerIdentity(new GetCallerIdentityRequest())
        .getAccount();
```